# Linker error: ld: library not found for -lssl

Tags: mysql, ssl, makefile, linker-errors, linker-flags

When linking my program on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1, I get an error message

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The linker flag `-lssl` is returned by `mysql_config` in the makefile:

```
LFLGS := $(shell mysql_config --libs)
```

The makefile had been working fine for quite some time, so I suspect the problem was caused by upgrading macOS recently. I also updated mysql to the latest version, 5.7.20, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: None of the nearly 5,000 existing posts found by searching for *ld: library not found for -lssl* helped? You've read them all and not a one of them gave you any idea how to go about fixing this problem?

Comment: @KenWhite: None of the ones I've read has helped.

Comment: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/795 number one in google search for macos+lssl

Comment: @AlexCohn: That solved it, thanks. I also just realised why I didn't get any google results: a dash prefixing a word excludes that term from the search. Clearly not what I wanted!